# list out all computer node connected to master node

Tags: ssh, port, slurm, connectivity

I have HPC access, connected to other HPC via local IP or just simple hostname (i.e., compute1 or node3). I can log in to them by typing "ssh node3" or its IP like "ssh 10.2.6.20"
How can I list out all such connected nodes?
The system doesn't have SLURM or PBS, neither I am a root user.

Answer (score 1):

just type

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

got all listed nodes